# Spark RDD Memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory, rdd

```
val rddMap = rdd.map(x=>x*x)
val rddReduce = rddMap.reduce((a:Int,b:Int) => a + b)
```

At which step will be the data loaded into the Memory of worker node?

Comment: the second step because it is an action while the first step is a transformation

Answer (score 1):

to load the data into memory, you need to use `.cache` in your code.